# get the referer url in python/webapp2 for a post request

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I want to get the referer url that has sent in the request to the server. 
I am using the webapp2 framework on appengine.

when i do:

```
def post(self, slug):
    print self.request
```

i get the following output:

```
OST /first/person/ HTTP/1.0 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8 Cache-Control: max-age=0 Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 43 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content_Length: 43 Content_Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Cookie: djdt=hide; csrftoken=09f29b2bfe9f51f16581bab7fe7c6f38; sessionid=49b995d954eae8d613cedc3f4e92a796 Host: 127.0.0.1:8080 Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080 Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/person/1/
```

as is clearly visible there is `Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/person/1/`

i am interested in only the referer, hence i tried:

```
referer = self.request.headers['Referer']
            print referer
```

which gives the output:

```
False Status: 200 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 0 Cache-Control: no-cache
```

One way of getting would be to do string processing on request, but i am sure there would be something more standard.

Comment: You can access the `Referer` header by attribute as well: `self.request.referer`.

Comment: even that returns: *False Status: 200 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 0 Cache-Control: no-cache*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned in your comment, this happens in webapp2, however if you want to redirect the user to the location from where the request has come, it can be as simple as:

```
webapp2.redirect(self.request.referer)
```

Answer (score 2):

For a post request `self.request.referer` does not work. This only works for a get request.

What you can do is save the referer in a cookie when the get request comes in (which is usually before you post something) and then when you post you access that cookie.

```
def get(self):
    self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'referer=%s; Path=/' % self.request.referer)
    # render your html
def post(self):
    # your logic here
    referer = str(self.request.cookies.get('referer'))
    self.redirect(referer)
```

A global variable should work, too.

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you're interested in the original referrer but are deeper in the code and don't have direct access to the request, querying the env seems to work:

```
original_referrer = os.environ.get('HTTP_REFERER')  # NOTE: spelling is correct
```

The result, locally, is something like

```
http://0.0.0.0:8001/myendpiont/someid?a=true
```